# How to solve ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID for local testing on iPhone / Mobile devices?

Tags: iis

I have a WebApi written in c# as my beckend and an Angular app that makes api call's to that API to fetch and post the data.

The issue is that after hosting the website to my IIS on local computer when i run the website i get `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error on my API's... in windows i can just click 'Go to localhost (not secure)' and all request will be accepted. The issue is that when i'm trying to test the application via a mobile device like iPhone, the Angular App is running but no data is fetched as the call to API is rejected due to `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`.

In my IIS i've created two binding on port 5000 (http) and 5001 (https with self signed certificate)

Comment: Run a report and the results should be clear, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, to solve the `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error you should let the iphone truest the self signed certificate. I suggest you could try to follow this [article](https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/self-signed-certificates-in-ios-apps-ff489bf8b96e) to solve this issue.

Besides, if possible I suggest you could try to buy or create a trusted certificate when you do some local test in Iphone.